# Edit cell above cell that called a function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using Google Apps Script to make a function that will be called in a Google Sheet. The function does some auto calculating for a spell effect. Some spells need the player to provide extra info (How many people are you shielding, etc) and some don't need any additional inputs. If extra info is needed, the user provides it in the cell directly above the cell that calls the function. I'll call this the "input cell" for clarity. The "function cell" is the one that calls the function, directly below the input cell.

My question is this: if the extra info is unneeded, as determined by conditionals within the function, how do I overwrite the contents of the input cell with '-'? I can't put a formula within that cell directly, because the user would overwrite the formula when entering the additional information. The function also returns a value to the cell that called it.

I've tried a bunch of techniques but I can't figure out how to do it.

- I tried returning an array of both values, but it flows downwards instead
  of upwards, and I couldn't find anything for "return array offset
  upwards" or something to that effect.
- I can't use absolute references
  like "L17" because the function can be called from many places on the
  sheet, and it also only needs to mess with the cell directly above it.
- using `setValue()` or `setValues()` threw a "no permission" error.

I would attach my code, but it's a mess of half-deleted attempts that didn't work, and wouldn't be much help at all. I also don't want to ask anything too specific, for fear of running into the https://xyproblem.info problem. I just want to be able to have a function edit the cell directly above it, and I don't care about which technique gets that accomplished.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See  [Should I include tags in title?](/help/tagging)

Comment: Ah thank you! I'm used to other places where that was common practice, didn't realize that tags were indexed by search engines as well.

Comment: I believe you can achieve this using the [`onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) Simple trigger. The idea would be to “detect” the edited cell and if applicable, display the results on the offset of the current cell as `(row-1, column)` (If within bounds). However I would be able to provide a more detailed explanation if I had a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Are you able to provide a simplified version of your spreadsheet exemplifying the desired results?

Answer (score 1):

No cell can contain both a formula(or a output of a formula) and simultaneously contain a user entered value.  That was always the case with any spreadsheet, Excel or Google sheets or any other. It's one or the other. Choose one and redraw your logic!

For your specific problem, if you can reflow your logic, you might try simple triggers like `onEdit`.

Comment: I may have phrased my question unclearly. What I meant was, "at any point in time, depending on what's selected, it will either have a user-entered value or be filled with a formula."

However I figured out a workaround. I was only going to fill it with whitespace anyways to delete what the user had, and basically that can be accomplished by using a conditional formatting formula to set both the text and the cell color to the same color of gray.